# How to get SQL Query from a view in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a database in my sql server and I also created one view in it to store a really long, I mean a really long query. And I need to use this query to fill a SqlDataAdapter in VB

Basic example with very straight easy query on how to fill a SqlDataAdapter

```
adapter.Fill("Select * from products")
```

I only wish my query was this simple and straight forward, instead i have a monster of a query and dont't want / cant't just paste it in my code. Isn't there another way to access it like so:

```
adapter.Fill(dataSet.ViewWithLongQuery)
```

The Dataset here contains my View

Thanks!

Comment: Can you call the view instead of the table name? Something like `Select * FROM <myViewName>`?

Comment: Yep it works as intented than you very much my friend

Comment: James - Glad that worked for you.  I have posted the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was posted as a question in a comment, so I will convert it to an answer.
Select directly from the view.

`Select * FROM <myViewName>`